# How can I retrieve an entire row of a MAX query?

Tags: sql, database

[image: TABLE.PNG]

Im currently using this query in attempts to retrieve the highlighted rows

"Select max(grades_id) from grades WHERE dt_year BETWEEN 2012 AND 2013 GROUP BY student_id HAVING count(grades_id) >= 2"

however it is only yielding

[image: RESULTS.PNG]

is there any way to retrieve the entire row as opposed to just the grades_id?

Comment: If you want to retrieve the highlited rows, the answer given by    Lord Peter.

Answer (score 1):

Just use your existing query as a subquery to determine the rows you want, and select all the columns for them, like this:

```
select * from grades where grades_id in (Select max(grades_id) from grades WHERE dt_year BETWEEN 2012 AND 2013 GROUP BY student_id HAVING count(grades_id) >= 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
SELECT g.*
FROM grades g
WHERE g.grades_id = (SELECT MAX(g1.grades_id)
                     FROM grades g1
                     WHERE g1.dt_year BETWEEN 2012 AND 2013
                     AND g1.student_id = g.student_id
                     HAVING count(g1.grades_id) >= 2)
```

If you can your data insert in http://sqlfiddle.com/ maybe I can more optimal solution give.